# In audio file `MediaPlayer.getDuration()` from URL return 0

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to get the duration of a .ogg audio file from the web. I always get -1 as result of getDuration(). Here's my code:

```
String audioUrl = "URLHERE";
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioUrl);
mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); //Also tried with prepare(), same result
```

Inside OnViewCreated method of my fragment I use the setOnPreparedListener to know when MediaPlayer is prepared, and here I use the getDuration method:

```
 mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                int duration = mp.getDuration(); //ALWAYS -1
            }
        });
```

So here I always get -1. I don't think is because of the audio format, because the audio is loaded correctly, and with the .start() method I can hear it.

Comment: I think is because is a Streaming read this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#getDuration()

Comment: If you want the duration you will need to download the `ogg` and load it to `MediaPlayer` after not connecting directly to the streaming

Comment: You can only get the duration once your mediaplayer goes into started state.

Comment: Also in started state I can't get the duration.
About the sreaming, I will try to download and retry with an offline version of the file. Sad that I can't get the duration of an audio without downloading it. I will post here results

Comment: Are you doing live streaming? If yes media player will not return duration

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by live streaming? I just fetch some short audio like 2-3 sec..

Comment: Edit: By downloading the file I can get correctly the duration with getDuration. So I suppose that loading it from an Url cause a non working getDuration method. Thanks to all

Comment: What did you use to download it?